# Vue Component Reference Error

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, vue.js, vue-component

I made a Vue component that displays a modal to ask the user whether they want to play as 'X' or 'O'. It's supposed to be able to do this by having a v-on:click='startComp('X') - but this isn't working, it's throwing a Reference Error and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been at this for a few days now...

The reason I am trying to call the function in the first place is because I need the v-on:click to both set **this.modal** to false (thus removing the modal and transitioning to the 'board') and set **this.marker** to its respective value. And afaik, you can only set 1 item in a v-on:click.

[Here is a forked version of my original Codepen for testing this.](http://codepen.io/Dirtier/pen/bwvwLA)

**Edit - Sorry, this thing just flat out will not let me format the code correctly.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
<transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-container">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <slot name="body">
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 select_marker" 
                            id="SX" 
                            v-on:click='compStart("X")'>X</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 select_title">
                                SELECT<span style='color:#00B16A'>MARKER</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 select_marker" 
                            id="SO" 
                            v-on:click='compStart("O")'>O</div>
                        </div>
                    </slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</transition>
```

```
compStart(marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
        this.showModal = false;
        this.start('comp');
    },
```

Comment: *"Edit - Sorry, this thing just flat out will not let me format the code correctly."* - Try spaces instead of tabs for indenting. (Plus each line should be indented with (a minimum of) four spaces so that it is recognised as code.)

Answer (score 0):

So after 3 days of smashing my head against the wall, I finally figured this out. I guess the modal wasn't inside the targetted element for Vue, so instead of v-on:click='compStart("X")' it needed to be v-on:click='game.compStart("X")'.